# Combine array into a simpler array (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array that looks like this. I'm looking at condensing this down into a simpler array (see below) how would I go about this?

```
array(1552) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "3792"
    [1]=>
    string(2) "99"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "3792"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "100"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "3792"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "101"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "3792"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "102"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "3792"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "103"
  }
  [5]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "3792"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "104"
  }
  [6]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "3832"
    [1]=>
    NULL
  }
}
```

I would like to condense it down

```
array(1552) {
  [3792]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "99"
    [1]=>
    string(2) "100"
    [2]=>
    string(2) "101"
    [3]=>
    string(2) "102"
    [3]=>
    string(2) "103"
    [3]=>
    string(2) "104"
  }
  [3832]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    NULL
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a quick 'n dirty way to do it

```
<?php
$result = array();

// assuming your data is named $data...
foreach ($data as $pair) {
  if (!array_key_exists($pair[0], $result)) {
    $result[$pair[0]] = array();
  }
  $result[$pair[0]][] = $pair[1];
}
```

Another way would be to use [array_reduce](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php)

```
$data2 = array_reduce($data, function($res, $pair) {
  if (!array_key_exists($pair[0], $res)) {
    $res[$pair[0]] = array();
  }
  $res[$pair[0]][] = $pair[1];
  return $res;
}, array());
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you original data is in `$array`, try this

```
$out=array();
foreach ($array as $a)
  if (!isset($out[$a[0]])) $out[$a[0]]=array($a[1]);
  else $out[$a[0]][]=$a[1];
```

This should giveyour desired structure in `$out`.